# Auto Layout with Container

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, containers

Using Auto Layout, I would like the colourful `UIViewControllers` to be responsible for their own heights, although the constraint of the container holding them is inside the main `UIViewControllers`. Maybe this can somehow be achieved using protocol and delegation? Any ideas?

- For encapsulation sake, colorful `UIViewControllers` shouldn't be exposed to the attributes of the main `UIViewController`

[image]

Something like this:

```
func updateMyHight()
{
    self.containerHoldingMe.heightConstraint.constant = 100
}
```

Comment: can u please elaborate little more.

Comment: Sure. Where would you like me to elaborate?

Comment: This is not a good use of view controllers.

Comment: @matt, How would you implement this otherwise?

Comment: I would go so far as to say that you might be overcomplicating your interface. You don't need so many controllers all with independent heights etc. Why not just have a UITableView and viewModels for cells? Then the system will calculate heights for you?

Comment: Firstly, unless there is more to each controller than color, you only need one with a property for the color. Secondly, you would be better to just use a UITableView and replace the controllers with cells driven from a data model withing the main controller. This has all the delegate calls you need to define the height. This will also allow you to scroll when you have more than fits on a screen.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel. 1. There is a lot more then color in every controller. 2. They are different all of them.  UITableView is for recurring cells. Do you think is suits here?

Comment: @DanielGalasko, what is viewModels?

Comment: @Luda the basic idea is to encapsulate your logic for each row into a custom class AKA ViewModel that understands how to transform the model logic to the view. Basically everything those child controllers are currently doing, except you don't have to worry about managing VC's and you can do lazy loading

Comment: @Luda UITableView is for presenting data of your choosing as rows in an order of your choosing. You decide what is in a row by returning a cell for it. You could easily do what you want using a table view and all using auto layout of the cell heights based on constraints in the contents.

Comment: @Luda All you need is _views_, not view _controllers_.

Comment: @matt, How do I put all these views in storyboard and make the logic?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answer attached.

**1. Code and Interface Builder** 
[image]

**2. Result**
[image]

Comment: That looks promising. Can you please send you code, for quick copy pasting? Or maybe upload it somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't work if you use regular segue of the container :-/

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIView and override `intrinsicContentSize`. If you play your cards right, you'll give your subclass a property that your `intrinsicContentSize` will consult. Now the views are setting their own heights, as far as autolayout is concerned.

If you also want them spaced evenly, use iOS 9's new UIStackView to distribute them. It obeys the intrinsic content size of its arranged views. Since the stack view can be configured in the nib, the entire exercise will basically consist of one line of code.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is the following:

1. Put a 'container view' in both the green and blue controller's views and constrain the top, leading and trailing to the viewcontroller's view.
2. Place in those containers the elements that causes them to be resized and constrain them in a way that the containers height depends on their contained elements.
3. Maintain a reference to the parent controller by  adding a weak
   property to both the green and blue controller in the
   `prepareForSegue` method in the parent controller.
4. Add an height constrain to the containers in the parent application and drag an IBOutlet to both of these constraint.
5. Once the green and blue controllers are loaded and the elements are resized,get the 'container' views height and assign them to the height constraints in the parent controller.

Comment: This answer is not that good when you have endless number of colourful controllers. If you control the size of each colourful controllers implisitly from the main controller, you lose the encapslation